# Anchor tag not taking height of its content

Tags: html, css

I have a short markup that I am making for clickable box. I want a certain full box to be clickable and so what I did was to put my box elements (`div` etc.) inside the anchor tag. Although linking is working this way, the anchor tag is not taking any height of the contents that's inside it (shows height 0px). Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pb4PL/1/ and a look of how the markup looks like:

```
<body>
    <div class="project-box">
        <a href="#" class="project-link">
            <div class="project-picture-container">
                <img src="sample.jpg" alt="project image">
            </div>
            <div class="project-desc-container">
                <div class="project-heading-container">
                    <h2 class="project-heading">
                    Project Name
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <h3 class="project-desc-heading">
                    This is the description about the project.
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="project-desc"
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Why doesn't anchor take the height of its content? In addition, here the parent of the anchor tag that is the `div` element also doesn't seem to be taking any height of the contents inside it. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML and CSS code is not valid, but i worked with it and this is the valid one with the solution that I think it's ok.

### CSS:

Remove the position from the link element and add display block to it.

```
img {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}

img:hover { border: 2px solid blue }

.project-box {
    width: 190px;
    position: relative;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    display: block;
}

.project-picture-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

.project-heading { font-size: 0.8em }

.project-heading-container {
    height: 15px;
    margin: 8px 0 4px 0;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

.project-desc-heading {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="project-box">
    <a href="#" class="project-link">
        <div class="project-picture-container">
            <img src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ps/359/823/3598236_300.jpg" width="182px" height="142px" alt="project image">
        </div>
        <div class="project-desc-container">
            <div class="project-heading-container">
                <h2 class="project-heading">
                    Project Name
                </h2>
            </div>
            <h3 class="project-desc-heading">
                This is the description about the project.
            </h3>
        </div>

    </a>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/aCElefa/1/)

Hope it works as you want.

Comment: But why does having `position` inside the css of `a` element affect its operation of getting the size the content inside it automatically?

Comment: I meant to ask why does `position:absolute` as I specified in my `a` element's css restrict it height : 0px? What is the reason behind removing `position` and adding `display:block` in css?

Comment: In the absolute position, the element will be positioned to it's parent relative element and will be removed from the document flow. But when we add display: block; the element will just take the block style and i think this is enough to get it working. We can remove the height and with of the link element as i updated the answer.

Comment: This worked for me.  height:100% was being ignored until I set display:block too.  Strange because the parent div was already set to block display; why wasn't it inherited?